# Can I use jblas mmul without temporary files?

Tags: java, jblas

I'm working on on an Apache crunch job using jblas with the constraint that I can't write any local files. I need to do just one operation that writes temporary files: mmul. For instance,

```
DoubleMatrix dm1 = new DoubleMatrix(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4);
DoubleMatrix dm2 = new DoubleMatrix(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4);
dm1.mmul(dm2);
```

tries to write a local file to a directory that looks like:

```
/var/folders/wv/m4qv0kg90xg2brgznm257rw40000gp/T/jblas8991904169789984821
```

Is there a way to do matrix multiplications without writing local files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration in Java that can change this; the temporary files are used by Lapack and Blas. I was able to make an exception for the temporary folders /var/folders on Mac and /tmp on Linux.